Запись блока script в .gitlab-ci.yml в артефакт
Нужна помощь, не догоняю как записать в артефакт выполнение всех команд в разделе script.
build:
  tags:
    - $RUNNER_TAG
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - docs/
    expire_in: 1 week
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.23.2-debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - mkdir docs
    - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker >> docs/build.txt
    - echo "Build completed" >> docs/build.txt
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - /kaniko/executor --cache --cache-repo $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $IMAGE_NAME
    - /kaniko/executor --cache --cache-repo $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $IMAGE_NAME_LATEST


